# Shrinkwrap or Boolean for die stamp template

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to blender and not sure what the right terminology would be. So please correct me and help me with that too.
What I have is a plane with a shape indented into it, which I want to use as a master template to create impressions in the faces of other surfaces on a cube. I'm thinking boolean operation for that but I'm lost on how to create the master die. I was thinking of shrinkwrap it onto a cube but that doesn't produce the positive mold I need for the boolean. I tried a boolean to the cube but didn't get what I wanted either.

Thank you,
Mark

[image: This is the template I want to repeat onto the faces of a cube]

Thanks to susu this is what I got for a result, just perject.

[image: So much better then the booleans I was working with.]

Comment: Hello, could you provide screenshots of your current setup so we can visualize it better ? Thanks

Comment: Rather than boolean, could you simply copy the faces to a waiting hole in your other object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avoid booleans, avoid shinkwrap**, one will give you headaches with bad topology, the other will yield Z-fighting problems...

Use Instancing:

Create your basic shape.

[image]

Add a cube.

[image]

Select the cube, and select Instancing->Faces.

[image]

Deselect the cube and select your shape. With the shape still selected press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and select the cube.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent the shape to the cube. Select **"Parent to Object"**
.

[image]

A cube with the basic shape on every face  will be created.

[image]

Then press Ctrl+A and select "Make Instances Real".

[image]

At that point you can go ahead and delete the cube.

The instances will become different objects but you can join them. Select all of them and pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Note that when you join the different objects in one, you will end with duplicated vertices. Use merge by distance to fix that.

Comment: Thank you, never seen that before. Did I miss a step though? When I did it orientation of the faces of my shape did not the cube.

Comment: Nobody can guess what steps you did or didn't do. if you don't show the results there is no way to help you further. Edit your original question and add information and images of what happened when you tried it.

Comment: Again thank you susu, your help was perfect, Because I didn't create the object originally the origin of the object was wrong. I changed it and the faces then oriented correctly. This is a wonderful technique to add to my toolbox of tricks, thank you so much.

Comment: Once I learned how to change the origin orientation and rotated the object a few times I even got the faces all correct.